# Installing faster-than-requests Python

Tags: python, pip

When using: pip install faster-than-requests
i get this error:

> WARNING: Discarding
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/9b/f392487c0ddb086aad681a781fbb1da4fcd2761920d20cfae18ecb724e67/faster_than_requests-21.03.03.zip#sha256=3cc247556e10c64d8897933304670c873236026b4ef9f219215b124e990c2dac
> (from https://pypi.org/simple/faster-than-requests/)
> (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1:
> python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> faster-than-requests (from versions: 21.3.3)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for faster-than-requests

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: I use python 3.9

Comment: My advice to you is to forget about `faster-than-requests` and use the well-known and well-understood `requests` module.  `faster-than-requests` is written in a non-mainline language, it is delivered in binary form, and makes performance claims that are sketchy at best.